# vistual studio code extension output window font color

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am new to vs code extension, based on the reference [vs code output](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#OutputChannel), the output font color can only be mono. Is that right? Or there is a way to colorize fonts in the output window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have seen the output window only shows only monochrome output. However the debug console can have colors.